# When referring to 'hadith' in plural, is it grammatically incorrect to address it as 'hadiths' and not 'ahadith'?

Tags: hadith, arabic

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith):

> A hadith (/ˈhædɪθ/ or /hɑːˈdiːθ/;[ Arabic: حديث‎ ḥadīth, **plural: ahadith, أحاديث, aḥādīth)** is one of various reports describing the words, actions, or habits of the Islamic prophet Muhammad.

This states that **ahadith is the plural of hadith.**
However, I have seen lots of times where the plural of hadith is **hadiths**.

**Question:** When referring to 'hadith' in plural, is it grammatically incorrect to address it as 'hadiths' and not 'ahadith'?

I just wondered if you could use both of them as the plural of hadith or just ahadith.

<sup>I would think this question is best suitable for a site like Arabic.SE but since there is no such sites, this questions would best be suitable to be asked on this site.</sup>

Comment: There's a proposal for Arabic language that might hopefully be launched and which I strongly invite anybody to support https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105382/arabic-language?referrer=E7543yclX-MBmqgt1wfCkA2 in this meta post https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/arabic-stackexchange-re-proposed I've explained how to do this for the proposal stage which we have passed. I think the question is hardly on-topic here and if it where it is opinion based.

Comment: @Medi1Saif   I thought it would be off topic but this site was the closest related site to the question I was asking so I might get an answer before it gets closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is hardly on-topic here as it is in first place about Arabic language and hardly related to Islam (see Meta posts such as [Should we allow questions regarding the Arabic language?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-we-allow-questions-regarding-the-arabic-language) and if it where it is opinion-based and a matter of choice as:

- some users would prefer to stick on the "correct" Arabic transliteration *ahadith* for the plural of *hadith*,
- while others would prefer to stick on English like style *hadiths* which maybe more intuitive for none Arabic speakers and converts etc.